# Can I make GND vias like this under my QFN package?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, integrated-circuit, kicad, qfn

[image]

Can I make GND vias like this under my QFN package?

Comment: I don't see why not, but someone with more experience might know a reason why not. I don't *think* it will cause any problem when reflowing solder. I guess you are doing this to improve thermal conduction?

Comment: This is a very general question. Can you be more specific? What is your actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: Probably yes. Ask your PCB manufacturer if they have any limitations regarding it.

Comment: Like what? With vias at all? Yes. I wouldn't use nearly so many as shown, however. 9 or 16 will be enough for a package that size.

Comment: More vias increases the amount of wicking, which increases the amount of excess solder paste needed to prevent voids.  TI recommends a 1mm grid but your devices manufacturer may have specific information for that device.

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa122/sloa122.pdf?ts=1656021405778

Comment: The TI recommendation is interesting. I once heard that one should be careful with "too regular" patterns because they could potentially form resonators. However, odds are that this is not relevant in most cases. What is the expected power dissipation of this component (just the order of magnitude)?